# JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I know that there were a lot of topics like this. And I know the basics: `.forEach()` operates on original array and `.map()` on the new one.

In my case:

```
function practice (i){
    return i+1;
};

var a = [ -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var b = [ 0 ];
var c = [ 0 ];
console.log(a);
b = a.forEach(practice);
console.log("=====");
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
c = a.map(practice);
console.log("=====");
console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

And this is output:

```
[ -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
=====
[ -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
undefined
=====
[ -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

I can't understand why using `practice` changes value of `b` to `undefined`.
I'm sorry if this is silly question, but I'm quite new in this language and answers I found so far didn't satisfy me.

Comment: It’s this simple: `.map` _returns a new array_, whereas `.forEach` _doesn’t return anything_. Basically, if you want to obtain a modified form of the previous array, you use `.map`, if you don’t want that, you use `.forEach`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what use does the javascript forEach method have (that map can't do)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034392/what-use-does-the-javascript-foreach-method-have-that-map-cant-do)

Comment: @Xufox - I red this topic before creating new one, but answer didn't satisfiy me.

Comment: Don’t just say it didn’t satisfy you. How exactly doesn’t it answer your question (have you read all the answers?)? What is your specific question that isn’t covered by the proposed duplicate target?

Comment: @Xufox That question deals with self-implemented functions, and is not really about the standardized ES5 functions.

Comment: See the article [JavaScript — Map vs. ForEach](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

Comment: See also the language-agnostic [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354909/1048572)

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct to say that forEach operates on the original array. I believe neither modifies the original array.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

They are not one and the same. Let me explain the difference.

`forEach`: This iterates over a list and applies some operation with side effects to each list member (example: saving every list item to the database) and does not return anything.

`map`: This iterates over a list, transforms each member of that list, and returns another list of the same size with the transformed members (example: transforming list of strings to uppercase). It does not mutate the array on which it is called (although the callback function may do so).

References

[Array.prototype.forEach() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: map return list and forEach not . OK

Comment: One extra thing to keep in mind if you encounter a codebase with `.map`s instead of `.forEach`'s: IE <=10 does not support the `.forEach`, so a much used workaround is to use `.map` instead

Comment: Are you sure that `forEach` modifies the original array?

Comment: @johnywhy Where in the answer does it state that?

Answer (score 107):

- [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) *“executes a provided function once per array element.”*
- [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) *“creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.”*

So, `forEach` doesn’t actually return anything. It just calls the function for each array element and then it’s done. So whatever you return within that called function is simply discarded.

On the other hand, `map` will similarly call the function for each array element but instead of discarding its return value, it will capture it and build a new array of those return values.

This also means that you *could* use `map` wherever you are using `forEach` but you still shouldn’t do that so you don’t collect the return values without any purpose. It’s just more efficient to not collect them if you don’t need them.

Comment: Of note: in 2015, it would have been arguable that `forEach` would have "been more efficient" than `map` especially if a polyfill was required to support `forEach` on an older browser (IE8 or 9). You don't need to assign the return of `map` to anything; the return value should get garbage collected immediately after `map` returns when the return of `map` is not assigned.

Comment: @cowbert Just because something is garbage collected immediately, that does not mean that you are not getting hit by the allocations that were necessary. So `forEach` will *conceptually* still be more efficient and better suited for tasks where you do not need to collect results. And I don’t know about you but in 2015, I was not developing for IE8 anymore (which btw. also didn’t support `map`); and IE9+ support `forEach`. And actually a month after my answer, Microsoft ended support for those browsers.

Comment: Are both forEach and map guaranteed to process the elements in the same order?

Comment: @Quentin2 Yeah, also, both functions are synchronous, so `map` and `forEach` calls will only return once the whole array has been looped through and the callback has been called for each.

Comment: If you use `map` in place of `forEach`, you're not "collecting" anything. So what's the harm?

Comment: @poke "forEach will conceptually still be more efficient" -- Does anyone have any statistics to support that?

Comment: @johnywhy The better question is how does abusing `map` benefit you?

Answer (score 82):

|  | forEach() | map() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Functionality** | Performs given operation on each element of the array | Performs given "transformation" on a "copy" of each element |
| **Return value** | Returns `undefined` | Returns new array with transformed elements, leaving back original array unchanged. |
| **Preferrable usage scenario and example** | Performing non-tranformation like processing on each element. For example, saving all elements in the database. | Obtaining array containing output of some processing done on each element of the array. For example, obtaining array of lengths of each string in the array |

**`forEach()` example**

```js
chars = ['Hello' , 'world!!!'] ;
    
var retVal = chars.forEach(function(word){
  console.log("Saving to db: " + word) 
})
  
console.log(retVal) //undefined
```

**`map()` example**

```js
 chars = ['Hello' , 'world!!!'] ;
    
 var lengths = chars.map(function(word){
   return word.length
 }) 
    
 console.log(lengths) //[5,8]
```

Answer (score 26):

The main difference that you need to know is `.map()` returns a new array while `.forEach()` doesn't. That is why you see that difference in the output. `.forEach()` just operates on every value in the array.

Read up:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array.prototype.map()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You might also want to check out:
 - [`Array.prototype.every()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 15):

**Performance Analysis**
For loops performs faster than map or foreach as number of elements in a array increases.

```js
let array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
  array.push(i)
}

console.time('map');
array.map(num => {
  return num * 4;
});
console.timeEnd('map');


console.time('forEach');
array.forEach((num, index) => {
  return array[index] = num * 4;
});
console.timeEnd('forEach');

console.time('for');
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = array[i] * 2;

}
console.timeEnd('for');
```

Comment: Here is the result on my computer: `map: 1642ms forEach: 885ms for: 748ms`

Comment: This test is not very scientific.
It'd need to test them all doing the same thing. map is building an array, foreach is editing an array in place, and the for loop is modifying the other array in place also.

When I modify the tests to actually do the same thing, map is faster than foreach.

Comment: I would argue it is scientific when used for the case of "I need to do something to each array element, what should I use?" question. For a direct comparison of all the operations then you're right, but for people who come here asking if map is quicker than forEach for just looping, this is a valuable answer.

Comment: @Anther wins this debate. I came to this page wondering if i can use map in place of forEach without sacrificing performance. The answer, if Anther's results are accurate, is "yes".

Answer (score 10):

**forEach()** :

- return value : **undefined**
- originalArray : **not modified** after the method call
- newArray is not created after the end of method call.

---

**map()** :

- return value : new Array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array
- originalArray : **not modified** after the method call
- newArray is created after the end of method call.

---

**Conclusion:**

Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the returned array is an anti-pattern; use forEach or for-of instead.

Comment: Based on reading this page, it seems there's no downside to using `.map` for everything. It's fewer characters to type, loops at least as fast as `.forEach`, and then i can just remember one method.

Answer (score 10):

`map` returns a new array.

`forEach` has no return value.

That's the heart of the difference. Most of the other answers here say effectively that, but in a much more convoluted way.

Answer (score 9):

forEach: If you want to perform an action on the elements of an Array and it is same as you use for loop. The result of this method does not give us an output buy just loop through the elements.

map: If you want to perform an action on the elements of an array and also you want to store the output of your action into an Array. This is similar to for loop within a function that returns the result after each iteration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The difference lies in what they return. After execution:

```
arr.map()
```

returns an array of elements resulting from  the processed function; while:

```
arr.forEach()
```

returns undefined.

Answer (score 4):

> **Difference between forEach() & map()**

**forEach()** just loop through the elements. It's throws away return values and always returns undefined.The result of this method does not give us an output .

**map()** loop through the elements allocates memory and stores return values by iterating main array

**Example:**

```
   var numbers = [2,3,5,7];

   var forEachNum = numbers.forEach(function(number){
      return number
   })
   console.log(forEachNum)
   //output undefined

   var mapNum = numbers.map(function(number){
      return number
   })
   console.log(mapNum)
   //output [2,3,5,7]
```

> **map() is faster than forEach()**

Comment: How do you know `map` is faster than `forEach`?

Answer (score 3):

One thing to point out is that both methods skips uninitialized values, but map keeps them in the returned array.

```
var arr = [1, , 3];

arr.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});
//Expected output: 1 3

console.log(arr.map(element => element));
//Expected output: [1, undefined, 3];
```

Comment: In Node.js v14.15.0, the output of `console.log(arr.map(element => element));` is `[ 1, <1 empty item>, 3 ]`.

Answer (score 3):

**Diffrence between Foreach & map :**

**Map()** : If you use map then map can return new array by iterating main array.

**Foreach()** : If you use Foreach then it can not return anything for each can iterating main array.

**useFul link** : use this link for understanding diffrence

https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Answer (score 3):

One of the subtle differences not mentioned here is that `forEach()` can loop over a static (not live) `NodeList` while `map()` cannot

Works perfectly:

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('.score')
    .forEach(element=>console.log(element));
```

Uncaught "TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function":

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('.score')
    .map(element=>console.log(element));
```

Comment: The NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll()` is not an array. It happens to `forEach()`. That imply that 1. a NodeList has to implement a `.map()` methid. It is perfectly fine it it doesn't. 2. It doesn't imply that `map()` cannot loop over a NodeList - the `.map()` method is generic and applicable to any array-like, so `Array.prototype.map.call( document.querySelectorAll(".score"), element=>console.log(element) )` would work.

Comment: @VLAZ Your comment is unclear. Can `.map` iterate over nodes or not? Is the code in this answer wrong?

Comment: @johnywhy "*Can .map iterate over nodes or not?*" yes, it can. I've demonstrated how. "*Is the code in this answer wrong?*" the code - no. Well, except `document.querySelectorAll('.score').map(element=>console.log(element));` but it does mention it throws an error. The *text* is wrong. NodeList and arrays both have a `.forEach()`. Trying to call a method with the same name on two different objects, doesn't imply which object the method can operate on.  So, the error is not  related to `.map()` itself but because to NodeList. And array's `.map()` can be applied to  NodeLists.

Comment: @VLAZ Thx! So you agree that `map` can be used instead of `forEach` in all cases?

Comment: @johnywhy no, I don't. Only use it *when you do mapping*. Don't use it when you don't do mapping. Use a loop or `.forEach` for those.

Comment: @VLAZ Why? What's the impact on code, readability, performance, etc?

Comment: @johnywhy [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693). Performance is indeed one aspect. But readability is a very big other aspect. Overall, you can use a hammer to spread butter on your sandwich but the performance and maintainability of that sandwitch would not be the same as if you used a knife.

Comment: @VLAZ According to tests performed by a few people on this page, `map` will perform at least as fast as `forEach`, or faster. So if performance is the question, `map` is equal to or better than `forEach`. What do you mean about "maintainability"?

Comment: @johnywhy the tests probably don't account for GC runs afterwards. As for maintainability - do you reckon it's completely reasonable and expected `person.getName()` will *delete* the person? Because I personally don't. And for the very same reason, I don't think `arr.map()` is maintainable if it doesn't do mapping. Breaks expectations, misuses idioms, it's hard to reason about and potentially refactor, without being thoroughly familiar with details that are supposed to be abstracted away.

Comment: @VLAZ `person.getName()` will delete the person?

Comment: @johnywhy example analogous to using `.map()` for operations that aren't mapping. Normally, the expectation is that `getX` will not change anything and just give you `X`. Similar to how `.map()` sets up the expectation that a transformation is being made and it would give you the transformed values. You seem surprised indicating that your expectation for `person.getName()` is subverted. Same thing happens when `.map()` is misused. Subverted expectations. As I said, it makes the code harder to reason about.

Comment: @VLAZ Bad comparison. `map` doesn't delete, modify, or damage anything. You could also create a new array using forEach instead of map, and it would be valid code. map just makes it a bit easier.

Comment: @johnywhy no, it's a very apt comparison. It's not *supposed to*. The same way `getName()` also not *supposed to*. You yourself suggested that it's interchangeable with `.forEach()` which then means that mutation is to be tolerated, yet it goes counter to what mapping is. I really don't think this is getting anywhere as you seem to be trying to deliberately ignore what I'm saying. So, here is hopefully the last thing to say:  If you tolerate code like `arr.map(x => { arr.shift() })` that's on you, just know you're wrong for doing so.

Comment: i'm listening very carefully to what you're saying, and you seem to be making a false statement. You're asserting that if `map` is used instead of `forEach`, the array will definitely get mutated. That seems obviously false. Neither function, map or forEach mutate the original array. Before `map` or `forEach` existed there wasn't any loop statement which returned an array.

Comment: `forEach` could be used to mutate the original array, same as `map`. No difference.

Comment: @johnywhy No, I'm not saying that using `.map()` will mutate the array. I said it shouldn't be used *when not doing a mapping operation*. You disagreed with that. Thus you are saying that `.map()` should be used for non-idiomatic purpose. The entire point with `getName()` is that - using a non-idiomatic code hurts the clarity.

Comment: "*forEach could be used to mutate the original array, same as map. No difference*" the ***only*** valid `.forEach()` call is one that has side-effects. This is quite different to the idiomatic `.map()` call which doesn't. Just how `getName()` would idiomatically not have side-effects.

Comment: Aside from map and forEach, there are myriad functions one can create, some which return something, some which don't, some which have side-effects, some which don't, with no clues given to someone reading the code (like "oh, they're using map, so this is supposed to return an array"). In myriad cases, there are no available clues as to whether or not a function  returns something other than *reading the code and comments*. So it seems a bit absurd to be so strict about this one limited case (map vs forEach) when so much other code doesn't offer such signposts.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm playing devil's advocate here, but sincere. Using map instead of forEach appeals because that simplifies my coding effort. You're insisting to use a less performant, less capable iterator, simply for self-documentation. But self-documentation is about meaningful variable names and function names supported by rich commenting, which I already do. In some languages, there's only ONE iterator -- people manage. https://www.sitepoint.com/self-documenting-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

.map and .forEach will do just about then same thing, until you start operating on arrays with millions of elements. .map will create another collection with the same size (and possibly type, depending on the array species) which could use up a LOT of memory. .forEach will not do this.

Comment: I specified that difference above.

Comment: @Asker this answer seems accurate to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Performance Analysis** (again - not very scientific)
In my experience sometime .map() can be faster than .foreach()

```js
let rows = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      // console.log("here", i)
      rows.push({ id: i, title: 'ciao' });
    }

    const now1 = Date.now();

    rows.forEach(row => {
      if (!row.event_title) {
        row.event_title = `no title ${row.event_type}`;
      }
    });

    const now2 = Date.now();

    rows = rows.map(row => {
      if (!row.event_title) {
        row.event_title = `no title ${row.event_type}`;
      }
      return row;
    });

    const now3 = Date.now();

    const time1 = now2 - now1;
    const time2 = now3 - now2;
    console.log('forEach time', time1);
    console.log('.map time', time2);
```

On my macbook pro (late 2013)

- forEach time 1909
- .map time 444

Comment: It's great to have these stats! At the moment, based on what i've read here, it seems i can just use `.map` in place of `.forEach` as standard practice. One question is: can map and forEach both iterate over nodes?

Answer (score -3):

**Map implicitly returns while forEach does not.**

This is why when you're coding a JSX application, you almost always use map instead of [forEach to display content in React](https://theforge.ca/react-for-loop-arrays-objects-map/).

Comment: No, this is completely wrong as of this writing. `map` does not "implicitly return", whatever that means. Instead, it explicitly returns a new array.