# Should I use array methods like map and filter, if I'm not going to return anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, eslint

In the last year I've been using array methods like *map* and *filter* more often instead of the standard for loop on an array. It feels simpler to read and write, and does all the things I'm most likely going to do anyway, like create a local variable.

Often times I don't return anything though. Eslint doesn't like me very much though. According to them, they say you always need a return, otherwise its *"probably a mistake"*
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return

**Why?** Is just good practice? What are downsides of a return-less array method?

*Been thinking on this for a while. Any insight or thoughts would be great.*

Comment: Why do you use `map`/`filter`  instead of `forEach`, if you do not use the result of those functions?

Comment: ESLint is correct - if you don't have a `return` statement in a `map` or `filter` callback then you are indeed most likely misusing it. They *rely* on the return value to function. Otherwise you are just looping over the array for no real reason. In that case, you should be using `.forEach`

Comment: You can also use the [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: Honestly, don't know why I didn't consider forEach on this. This is why I use eslint as well, as it annoys the crap out of me until I change. :)

Comment: Per the responses, I added a pull request to the to the eslint docs to help direct others. Thanks yall. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/10301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I use array methods like map and filter, if I'm not going to return anything?

No, you should not.

> Why? Is just good practice?

Yes.  It is a good practice to use the appropriate iteration method for the type of iteration you are doing.  There are numerous ways to iterate for a reason.  Pick the appropriate mechanism.

> What are downsides of a return-less array method?

Using `.map()` and `.filter()` without actually returning anything from the callback have the following downsides:

1. **Your code is misleading.**  The point of `.map()` and `.filter()` is to iterate over the array and produce a new array.  When a developer reads some code and sees `.map()` or `.filter()` being used, they expect that there should be a returned array.  When they don't see it being done that way, they will be confused, will initially feel like they don't understand the code.  If I were doing a code review on code like this, I would not approve of code like this.
2. **Your code unnecessarily creates objects that are not used.**  That's just wasteful and is not a good practice.  Instead, use an iteration method that does not produce an output array such as `for/of`, a regular `for` loop or `.forEach()`.
3. **Your code won't lint.**  Linters provide objections to things for a reason.  Using `.map()` or `.filter()` without returning anything from the callback is, just as the linter says, "probably a programming mistake" because that is not how those functions are designed to be used and there are appropriate alternatives when you don't want a returned array.

So, if you're just trying to do an iteration without creating any resulting array, use `for/of` or `.forEach()` or some other iteration scheme that isn't specifically designed to create an output array that you don't want.

Comment: Isnt this basically what the answer of adam says?

Comment: @JonasW. - No, not at all.  This is a much more complete answer that directly addresses the questions the OP asked and explains the reasoning.  In addition, Adam's answer mentions only one of the three points I mention.  The idea on stack overflow is to write the best answer you can.  Do you think Adam's answer is a better, more complete answer than this one?

Comment: @JonasW. if you're going to go down that route, all of the answers here will basically be the same. Because the core issue here is that OP doesn't seem to understand array methods and their usage. Yet each can explain things differently, so they can all be of use

Comment: @vlaz that still does not justify the two downvotes on his answer.

Comment: @JonasW. perhaps so. Yet it is also completely unrelated.

Comment: I don't really care about the downvotes - I assume they are from my inappropriate, snarky first line - but the point is the OP demonstrated that **they do understand how these methods work**, it seems like every answer other than mine felt the need to explain how they work to somebody who obviously already knew.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know about the difference between Map/Filter and forEach.

resuming.. forEach is mostly used when you want iterate an array with/as a procedure. [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Map and Filter are related to a callback function applied on every iteration. 
The return statement of those is what is going to be evaluated, not the function By the Map/Filter function at the end. Reason why it's needed.  Althought JS allows "whatever" And of course you are able to define that function what comes to our understanding as "The filter".

For Filter you can see that "true" and "false" as when the "data" is going to be filtered or not.

Answer (score -1):

basically you can loop with `map` or `forEach`/`for`, the difference are the following:

**foreach:** This iterates over a list and applies some operation with side effects to each list member, this means that you are transforming THE CURRENT ARRAY you are looping.... or as noticed by @TiagoCoelho, you dont mess with the array at all, just loop thought it.

**map:** This iterates over a list, transforms each member of that list, and returns another list of the same size with the transformed members, this means that you will get a BRAND NEW ARRAY with the modified items and you will also have in memory your old array.

so basically it depends on what you want to do with the data inside of your array.

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

examples:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//multiply each item for 2, it will stay on the same array.
a.forEach(i => {
  i = i * 2
})


//multiply the items of B for 2 but it will return a new array
var c = b.map(i => {
  return i * 2
})

console.log(a); //modified reference
console.log(b); //stays the same
console.log(c); //new array
```

Comment: foreach does not require you to modify the current array... you may be doing something to another array or variable, or sending network requests, or console.logs or whatever

Comment: @TiagoCoelho you are correct, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Neither `map` nor `forEach`  change the array on which those functions are called. Both `map`  and `forEach` modify the elements that are stored in the array, if you do changes on the element that is passed to callback.

Comment: also, your example does not change the original array

Comment: @TiagoCoelho in fact, `.forEach` does *not* modify the array at all, unless you do that manually yourself.

Comment: As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLbb30ub/1/) there is no difference in how `map`, `filter` and `forEach` treat the original array and their elements. The the difference is in their return value (that `map`  and `filter`  create a new array).