# usage of spread syntax code with map function

Tags: javascript

I have some familiarity with the ... operator[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

and recently I saw a developer use the spread syntax (as attached in snippet as ) [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button')].map((button)=> button.addEventListener('click',Add));

the above **... spread syntax with the map function** looks tough for me to understand, can someone help me understand it in simple terms conceptually..thanks for your time

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  var temp = [];
  var arrayOfStrings = [];

  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button')) //choose button only in the wrapper div and not the others like CLR
  //listen to only button events(other than the CLR)
  document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button').forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', Calculat));
  //listen to CLR button events
  document.getElementById('clear1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    temp = [];
    arrayOfStrings = [];
    document.querySelector('.my_flex').textContent = ('');
  });

  function Calculat(e) {
    z = e.target.innerText;
    //   console.log(z);
    document.querySelector('.my_flex').append(z); //append to the flex object
    if (z == '=') {
      document.querySelector('.my_flex').append(eval(arrayOfStrings));
      return false;
    }
    temp.push(z);
    arrayOfStrings = temp.join("");
  }

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 7cm;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  line-height: 3.5;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  /*align the text f the button to the center*/
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 0, 0, 1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  line-height: 3.5;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 0, 0, 1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.my_flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a>Calculations(Simple Mathematics only, example: 1+7,2*8 etc):--</a>
<div id="wrapper">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <br>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>+</button>
  <button>-</button>
  <button>*</button>
  <button>0</button>
  <button>(</button>
  <button>)</button>
  <button>/</button>
  <button>=</button>
  <button>.</button>
</div>
<div><button id="clear1">CLEAR</button></div>
<div class="my_flex">
  <!--just to get nice output on flex canvas -->
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like `[...document.querySelectorAll(...)]` is for copying the iterable/"array-like" result from `querySelectorAll` to a proper `Array` so you can then use `.map` and such on it.

Comment: Not all browsers support forEach on NodeLists.  Some require an actual array.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/

Comment: This is much easier to understand `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).map(...)`

Comment: is there a specification anyone can share that states that the nodelist(document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button') makes an array ..by using the code: [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button')]..

Comment: @James All browsers that support iterating node lists (i.e. spread syntax) also do support the `forEach` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just pointless to use the array spread syntax here, it's also [pointless (and indeed confusing) to use `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140181/1048572). This should rather use the [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', calculate);
});
```

or even better just a simple `for` loop:

```
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button')) {
    button.addEventListener('click', calculate);
}
```

Comment: the for loop is simpler to use.By the way i got a documentation question which is the code [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button')]  converts a nodelist to an array so for this do u have the specification regarding nodelist to array conversion using the ... spread syntax?

Comment: @logogomez [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) are silent on this (apart from mentioning that `for … of` works), but [the `NodeList` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) in the spec is marked as [`iterable`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-iterable), which [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is making use of.

Answer (score -1):

It's because that the result returned by querySelector is not an instance of Array.In other words the result has no map method and destructuring it inside of array will let you to use Array.prototype.map method on newly created array.

Comment: is there a MDN specification you can share that the nodelist(document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button') makes an array ..by using the code: [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper button')]..

Comment: "*the result returned by querySelector is not iterable*" - wrong. It's not an array, but it definitely is iterable, otherwise array spread syntax wouldn't work! Also, no destructuring going on here?

Comment: I think you need to read this part and think twice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol

Comment: @LevonGhazaryan [So](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#syntaxes_expecting_iterables)?

Comment: So since querySelector returns NodeList and it is an instance of Object which is not not defines @@iterable for it's instances and to make sure that everything is correct run this code in your browser console please  let foo = {};
for (let key of foo) {
    console.log(key);
}

Comment: And see the beauty of output

Comment: querySelectorAll returns NodeList but querySelector returns 1st element meaning not a nodelist right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: My apologies NodeList is @@iterable I guess browser does some manipulations here because the instances of Object are not @@iterable