# Javascript: specific examples of when you would use forEach instead of map?

Tags: javascript

I have a general understanding of the differences between forEach and map by reading docs and conversation with coworkers. I found this [post](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f) to be especially helpful. In the post, they suggest a time when you might want to use forEach:

> forEach() may be preferable when you’re not trying to change the data
>   in your array, but instead want to just do something with it — like
>   saving it to a database or logging it out

Can anyone else share times that they've intentionally used forEach instead of map?

Map seems to be preferable in most cases.

Comment: Search for `forEach` in any big open-source JS code. You'll find it.

Comment: `map` creates a new array, if you don't need a new array `map` wouldn't be a good choice.

Comment: You would never use `forEach`. When you don't need to produce another value (like `map` does), just use a `for…of` loop.

Comment: `map` **maps** original elements to new elements in a new array. If you're not doing any mapping without the need of a new array and just want plain iteration over an array, use `forEach`.

Comment: `forEach`and `map` serve completely different purposes. The former is for when you want to _do_ something with every element of an array. The latter is for when you want to _transform_ every element of an array into something else. Perhaps you could tell us why you think "Map seems to be preferable in most cases".

Comment: @Bergi That is, unless you're targeting IE and your project is not set up for ES5 transpilation.

Comment: @JLRishe If you're targeting old IE, you cannot use `forEach` either :-) You need either a polyfill or a transpiler anyway.

Comment: @Bergi `forEach` is natively supported in IE 9+ which surely covers 99% of remaining IE users. If you need to support anything older than that, it can _very easily_ be polyfilled. `for..of` cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `map()` if you want to create a *new* array containing the result of some operation on the elements of the original array. For instance:

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let squares = nums.map(n => n * n);
```

You use `forEach()` if you want to loop through the array, but aren't creating a new array with the results. It might be because you just want to perform some other operation using the elements of the array:

```
nums.forEach(n => console.log(n));
```

or you want to populate an array conditionally:

```
let evenSquares = [];
nums.forEach(n => {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        evenSquares.push(n * n);
    }
});
```

or you want to modify things in the array but don't need to return anything new:

```
let objects = [{a: 1}, {a, 2}, {a: 3}];
objects.forEach(obj => obj.a++);
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach() and map() perform 2 different functions. Briefly,

- foreach will iterate over every element in the list and do something
  with it.
- map on the other hand transforms a list. It iterates over
  every element in the list, does some operation to the list, and
  returns a new list.

This similar question has some great answers: [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)