# React - issue with displaying items in an array

Tags: reactjs, foreach

I have an array of locations that trying to show its value on my page, I used the following code to go through the array:

```html
{this.props.locations && this.props.locations.forEach(loc => {
    console.log("Location: "+loc)
    return(
        <span>Location is: {loc}</span>
    )
})}
```

The result on the page is nothing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPZCA.png)
However it logs the location correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUUxk.png)

I get the values of this.props.locations in App.js as below:

```html
 var locations = this.state.cardLists
      var distictLocations = new Set()
      locations.forEach(location => {
        if(!distictLocations.has(location.Location))
        {
          distictLocations.add(location.Location)
        }
      });
     this.setState({
       locations: distictLocations
     })
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since Set automatically makes sure it contains no duplicates, this check `if(!distictLocations.has(location.Location))` is not necessary.

Comment: Duplicate of [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](/q/34653612/4642212).

Answer (score 6):

`.forEach` method simply iterates over array elements but doesn't return anything.

If `locations` is an `Array` use `.map`:

```
{
    this.props.locations && this.props.locations.map(loc => {
        console.log("Location: " + loc)
        return (
            <span>Location is: {loc}</span>
        )
    })
}
```

If `locations` is a `Set` use `Array.from`:

```
{
    this.props.locations && Array.from(this.props.locations, loc => {
        console.log("Location: " + loc)
        return (
            <span>Location is: {loc}</span>
        )
    })
}
```

It is also recommended to add `key` prop to the mapped elements for performance reasons.

---

Recommended reading:

[forEach vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

[Lists and keys in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

[Reconciliation and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)

Comment: Thanks abadalyan, I got "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'" Error on using map

Comment: Updated the answer to account for `Set`