# How to push response in nested onject

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a nested data inside which I am trying to push my response I am getting from the server,

My data is :

```
let d = [{
    "dashId": 3,
    "dashName": "one",
    "dashData": []
  },
  {
    "dashId": 4,
    "dashName": "two",
    "dashData": [{
      "nestedId": 1,
      "nestedData": "how are you"
    }]
  }
]
```

This the data below I want to push

```
let res = [{
  "nestedId": 11,
  "nestedData": "I am fine"
}]
```

**What I am doing is:-**

```
let dd = d.map(li => {
  if (li.dashId === 3) {
    li.dashData.push(res)
  }
})

console.log(dd)
```

I am getting output as undefined

```
[ undefined, undefined ]
```

Comment: What is `d` in your last code block?

Comment: You should be returning from the map callback to specify what you want to map the current element to. You're not returning anything so you'll get undefined. Instead, you're changing your original `d` array's objects - See: [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693)

Comment: You need to return a value from `map` if you want to get a new array.

Comment: @Camilo  `d` is data to which I am maping

Comment: @expressjs123  OI tried returning like ` return li.dashData.push(res)` but it returns `[1, undefined]`

Comment: I think you should return `li` instead.

Comment: @Camilo could you write down working code with map

Comment: Sure, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.map` function creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. So the callback inside `map` should return an item and on your code, nothing is returned on callback.

In your case, it's better to use `Array.forEach` as follows.

```js
const d = [{
    "dashId": 3,
    "dashName": "one",
    "dashData": []
  },
  {
    "dashId": 4,
    "dashName": "two",
    "dashData": [{
      "nestedId": 1,
      "nestedData": "how are you"
    }]
  }
];

const res = [{
  "nestedId": 11,
  "nestedData": "I am fine"
}];

d.forEach(li => {
  if (li.dashId === 3) {
    li.dashData.push(...res)
  }
});

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return the `li` in your `map` callback:

```
let dd = d.map(li => {
  if (li.dashId === 3) {
    li.dashData.push(res)
  }
  return li
})
```

I'm not sure what do you need but I think `res` should not be an array:

```
const res = {
  "nestedId": 11,
  "nestedData": "I am fine"
};
```