# Why is my data undefined after mapping although the mapping was successful?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, mapping, observable

I have a function which returns an observable

```
  getData(){
    return this.http.get<{mat: any[], mat_auf: any[], mat_lok: any[], auf_an: any[]}>(this.authUrl + 'get/mat-data').pipe(
      map(({mat, mat_auf, mat_lok, auf_an}) => {
        console.log("AuthService", {mat, mat_auf, mat_lok, auf_an}); // correct data format
        mat.map(mat => {
          this.matAdapter.adapt(mat);
        });
        mat_auf.map(mat_auf => {
          this.mat_aufAdapter.adapt(mat_auf);
        });
        mat_lok.map(lok => {
          this.lokAdapter.adapt(lok)
        });
        auf_an.map(an => {
          this.aufAdapter.adapt(an)
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

The conversion by the adapters works fine if I look in the console but when I try to subscribe to the Observable in another component I get undefined:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.authSrv.getData().subscribe(res => console.log(res)) // res is undefined but why?
}
```

An adapter looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class MatAdapter implements Adapter<Mat>{
    adapt(mat: any): Mat {
        return new Mat(mat.ID, mat.name, mat.location);
    }
}
```

As I said the adapters work fine as in the console the correct object is logged.
But why is the data undefined, when I try to subscribe to the observable?
I think I use the map function wrongly.

Any help is appreciated. If further information is needed, please leave a comment.
Thank you

Comment: `console.log()` ***always returns `undefined`!!!*** so if you map to `console.log(something)` you *log* the value of `something* but *produce* the value `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ hey I just used console.log to see if the conversion was correct. But the data is still undefined if I leave out the console.log part. I change it to avoid misunderstandings. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, also, you don't even have a `return` statement in the first block with the `.map`. So when `getData()` is called it calls ` this.http.get().pipe(map())` but there is no mapping result. The implicit return is always `undefined`. "*hey I just used console.log to see if the conversion was correct*" please do **not** use `map` for simple iteration. Use `forEach` or an actual loop. It's extremely misleading for a start.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for all the information. Could you leave an example as answer, I would mark your answer!

Comment: I'd suggest reading [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693) as that's exactly the problem here is - performing a map over some data without returning anything.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you, you saved me few hours! It works now as expected

Comment: As additional tip specific to `rxjs`: If you want to perform a side effect on an observable without changing the observable, `rxjs` provides the `tap` operator. That would replace the outer map in your example.

Comment: @GunnarB. Thank you for this information!

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a value to a function with return-type void, you get undefined.

```
function addAndLog(x,y): void {
  console.log(`x + y = ${x + y}`);
}

const added = addAndLog(8,10);
consle.log(added);

// Output: 
// "8 + 10 = 18"
// undefined
```

I hope you can understand that even though I logged the two numbers added together, that doesn't mean `added` is given that value. `addAndLog` doesn't return a value and therefore `added` will always be `undefined`.

Your mapping operation maps every value it received to undefined. The function you give `map` is run and its return value is assigned as the *mapped* value. In this case you never return anything.

---

Rewritten to work:

```
function addAndLog(x,y): void {
  console.log(`x + y = ${x + y}`);
  return x + y;
}

const added = addAndLog(8,10);
consle.log(added);

// Output: 
// "8 + 10 = 18"
// 18
```