# Is it legit to use .map() method only for side-effects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, higher-order-functions, array.prototype.map

Is it legit (or good practice) do a loop with a higher order function - like `Array.map()` - to perform some side effects ?

This is mostly a theoretical question since I notice that sometimes I found (or perform myself) some loops using the `.map()` method, like this:

```js
let myObject = {...}
let myItemsArray = [ ... , ... ]

myItemsArray.map( (item, index) => {
    // do some side effect for ex: 
    myObject.item[index] = item
}
```

But I know that this `map()` method actually returns an array. So calling `myItemsArray.map()` is like I'm returning an array without assign it to any variable.

So the question, is this legit? Should I avoid this and use a classic `for()` loop or a `.forEach()` method?

**Side question**: one of the reasons I'm asking this is because I need to perform some loops on an async function so promises and await operators are involved, I remember that `forEach()` loops are not ideal on an async function, but wanted to know why.

Comment: Building an array you don't need is pointless, use `forEach` instead. But if you *are* doing asynchronous things it's possible you *do* need the array, because that's what `Promise.all` takes to resolve all of the promises.

Comment: you should just use `forEach` if you do'nt intend to actually map anything to a new array

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, indeed my code resolves some promises so the Promise.All() takes the result in the end

Comment: [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So the question, is this legit? Should I avoid this and use a classic for() loop or a .forEach() method?

If you aren't returning anything from the map function, then you should use `forEach` instead. You end up with the same result but you don't imply, to anyone maintaining your code, that you are returning something useful.

> one of the reasons I'm asking this is because I need to perform some loops on an async function so promises and await operators are involved, I remember that forEach() loops are not ideal on an async function, but wanted to know why.

Neither `forEach` nor `map` will `await` if the function you pass to it returns a promise (which `async` functions do).

So there are three possible scenarios here:

```
// Your loop
...myItemsArray...
// Code that comes after the loop
...etc...
```

A: The items in the loop need to handled **sequentially**

Use a regular `for ()` loop as the outer function won't pause.

B: The items in the loop can be handled in **parallel** and the code that comes after doesn't need to wait for it

Use a `forEach`.

C: The code that comes after needs to wait for everything in the loop to finish

Use a `map`. Pass the array of returned promises to `Promise.all`. Then `await` that.

Comment: Oh I get it now. So the `forEach()` is like the most "volatile" method here, right? I didn't know that it runs in parallel though. Always think that it was like the `for()` loop. 

So I'm guessing that not returning anything forEach() also keeps the memory clean? Where using map without implying it on a variable the returned array could remain in the memory of the session ?

Comment: Unless you `await` something, anything **asynchronous** in a loop will be done in parallel. With `for` an `await` will pause the whole loop. With `forEach` it will pause that specific function but the loop will continue on the other data in the meantime.

Comment: "So I'm guessing that not returning anything forEach() also keeps the memory clean?" —  No.