# using .map() instead of .forEach for creating an object

Tags: javascript, object

Here is a small sample of data that's representative of a larger dataset:

```
const data = [
    { id: 32, minimum: 200, maximum: 400 },
    { id: 16, minimum: 370, maximum: 390 },
    { id: 85, minimum: 700, maximum: 950 }
];
```

There is a need to create an object from this data using the `id` as the key and having the min and max as the value, like so:

[image]

The current approach for creating this object is the following -

```
let object = {};
data.forEach(o => {
    object[o.id] = { min: o.minimum, max: o.maximum }
});
console.log(object);
```

While this works, it seems like there should be a more concise way of writing this code.

I have experimented with `.map()` -

```
const obj = data.map(o => ({[o.id]: { min: o.minimum, max: o.maximum }}));
console.log(obj);
```

but the output is not in the correct format -

[image]

What should be changed in the `.map()` version to achieve the desired output format?

Comment: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: `map()` always creates an array.  That's what it does.  It takes one array and translates it into another.

Comment: [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// mapper simply creates the object that you want from the one that you have - id as the key and min and max are the values
const mapper = ({ id, minimum: min, maximum: max }) => ({ [id]: { min, max } });

const obj = data.reduce((acc, obj) => ({
   ...acc,
   ...mapper(obj)
}), {});
```

EDIT:

While reduce is the right way to do this - you are **reduce**ing an array to a single thing, JavaScript allows you various ways to do things. Here's an alternate solution using map and `Object.assign`:

```js
const mapper = ({ id, minimum: min, maximum: max }) => ({ [id]: { min, max } });

const obj = Object.assign(...data.map(mapper));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
and map the entries.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 32, minimum: 200, maximum: 400 }, { id: 16, minimum: 370, maximum: 390 }, { id: 85, minimum: 700, maximum: 950 }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(
        data.map(({ id, minimum: min, maximum: max }) => [id, { min, max }])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```