# How to overload the Set Class

Tags: javascript

How would I overload the [`Set.prototype.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) method, for example I'm trying to do:

```js
// allow overloading the Set().method function by passing multiple arguments
Set.prototype.add = function(x) {
    for (let x of arguments) {
        super.add(x); // doesn't Set act like a class?
    }
    return this;
}
let s = new Set([1,2,3]);
s.add(4,5,6);
console.log("Set: ", s);
// 'super' keyword unexpected here
```

Or do I need to alias it like this so I can call the parent via `Function.call/apply`, such as:

```js
Set.prototype.addMultiple = function(x) {
    for (let x of arguments) {
        Set.prototype.add.call(this, x);
    }
    return this;
}
let s = new Set([1,2,3]);
s.addMultiple(4,5,6);
console.log("Set: {" + Array.from(s) + "}");
```

Or, what about just aliasing the original method, is that considered ok? (or does `Set.prototype._add = Set.prototype.add;` have unintended side effects?):

```js
Set.prototype._add = Set.prototype.add;
Set.prototype.add = function(x) {
    for (let x of arguments) {
        Set.prototype._add.call(this, x);
    }
    return this;
}

let s = new Set([1,2,3]);
s.add(4,5,6);
console.log(`Set: {${Array.from(s)}}`);
```

Comment: If you want to call the method in the parent, you need to define a subclass, not overwrite the method in the `Set` class.

Comment: @Barmar how would that be done? Just with `class aliasedSet extends Set { ... }` ?

Comment: @Barmar similar to the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all of these fancy features; just `this`:

```
Set.prototype.addMultiple = function(x) {
    for (let x of arguments) {
        this.add(x);
    }
    return this;
}
```

While we're at it, let's use `const` instead in the loop:

```
for (const x of arguments) {
```

And also `arguments`? That's some 2010 code. Nowadays we use spread/variadic arguments:

```
Set.prototype.addMultiple = function (...args) {
    for (const x of args) { ... }
     
    // rest omitted
}
```

Keep in mind that extending/modifying native prototypes is generally frowned upon, so you're better off extending the class instead.

Comment: Thanks for this, that's very helpful. Noe question though: how does `this.add(x)` work, why doesn't that call itself and so produce an infinite loop?

Comment: Oh my god I'm sorry! `Set.prototype.add` => `Set.prototype.addMultiple` ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the `Set` with something like the following:

```js
class _Set extends Set {
    add(_) { 
        Array.from(arguments).map((x) => super.add(x));
        return this;
    }
}

let s = new _Set([1,2,3]);
s.add(4,5,6);
console.log(`Set: ${Array.from(s)}`);
```

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Comment: @VLAZ ok, but what's wrong with using `.map()` (I'm a beginner to js).

Comment: [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693)