# Looping in template literal returing undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate HTML code with two functions as a training exercise. The first function creates an individual list item. The second function takes an array with the actual items as input and creates the list, like so:

Function 1:

`` const listItem = item => `<li class="list-item">${item}</li>`; ``

Function 2:

`` const unorderedList = items => `<ul class="list">\n
  ${items.forEach((item) => { listItem(item); })}\n
  </ul>`; ``

The result should be something like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">car</li>
  <li class="list-item">bike</li>
  <li class="list-item">train</li>
</ul>
```

However my code returns

```
<ul class="list">
 undefined
</ul>
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `forEach` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeyer. Is there a way to have forEach return something? How would I use a ```forEach``` loop here instead of the solution with ```map``` below?

Comment: @MarkMeyer even if you return the value (removing the brackets) its still `undefined`

Comment: Hi @astarisborn please check some basic of js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: @astarisborn you can't use `forEach` this way inside a template because it won't ever return anything. The `map` solution is a good one. You can also use `reduce()`.

Comment: @Dadboz — the brackets aren't the issue. `forEach` returns `undefined` regardless of what you do inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you @MarkMeyer for the clarification and Rishab for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.map` to transform each `item` into a `listItem` result, and then join:

```js
const listItem = item => `<li class="list-item">${item}</li>`;
const unorderedList = items => `<ul class="list">\n
  ${items.map(listItem).join('')}\n
  </ul>`;

console.log(
  unorderedList(['car', 'bike', 'train'])
);
```

If you want newlines between each `<li>`, then join by newlines instead of the empty string (though it won't affect the rendered `<ul>`):

```js
const listItem = item => `<li class="list-item">${item}</li>`;
const unorderedList = items => `<ul class="list">\n
  ${items.map(listItem).join('\n')}\n
  </ul>`;

console.log(
  unorderedList(['car', 'bike', 'train'])
);
```