# Compare an Array to an Array of Objects and Return a new Array of Objects with Grouped Dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to format data so that it looks like  `desiredResult` right now its coming out as `result`. I do realize that I am kinda brute-forcing my way through the data but my algorithm skills are not great. I would appreciate any help trying to fix my code or pointing me in the direction to better understand how I could do this in a more efficient way.

```
var endResult = dates.map(function (item) {

  var arrayOfEvents = [];     

  var events = arrayOfObjects.map(function (value) {

    if (item === value.info.startDate) {
      arrayOfEvents.push(value)
      return arrayOfEvents
    } else{
      return ""
    }

  });

  return events

});

{JSON.stringify(endResult, null, 4)}
```

Array

```
var dates = 
[
"01-06-2020",
"01-07-2020",
"01-08-2020",
"01-10-2020",
"02-04-2020"
]
```

Array of Objects

```
var arrayOfObjects =
[
{
    "title": "Group President",
    "id": "TpNY1SU_",
    "info": {
        "description": "hi",
        "eventLocation": "change",
        "dailyActivity": "false",
        "startDate": "01-06-2020"
    }
},
{
    "title": "TEST",
    "id": "cEpPxopz",
    "info": {
        "description": "TEST",
        "eventLocation": "TEST",
        "dailyActivity": "true",
        "startDate": "01-07-2020"
    }
},
{
    "title": "Example",
    "id": "jnTMr_r7",
    "info": {
        "description": "example",
        "eventLocation": "Exmaple",
        "dailyActivity": "true",
        "startDate": "01-07-2020"
    }
},
]
```

Desired Result

```
var desiredResult = [
    [
        {
            "title": "Group President",
            "id": "TpNY1SU_",
            "info": {
                "description": "hi",
                "eventLocation": "change",
                "dailyActivity": "false",
                "startDate": "01-06-2020"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "TEST",
            "id": "cEpPxopz",
            "info": {
                "description": "TEST",
                "eventLocation": "TEST",
                "dailyActivity": "true",
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Example",
            "id": "jnTMr_r7",
            "info": {
                "description": "example",
                "eventLocation": "Exmaple",
                "dailyActivity": "true",
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        }
    ],
]
```

Actual Result

```
var actualResult = [
[
    [
        {
            "title": "Group President",
            "id": "TpNY1SU_",
            "info": {
                "description": "hi",
                "eventLocation": "change",
                "dailyActivity": "false",
                "startDate": "01-06-2020"
            }
        }
    ],
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
],
[
    "",
    [
        {
            "title": "TEST",
            "id": "cEpPxopz",
            "info": {
                "description": "TEST",
                "eventLocation": "TEST",
                "dailyActivity": "true",
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Example",
            "id": "jnTMr_r7",
            "info": {
                "description": "example",
                "eventLocation": "Exmaple",
                "dailyActivity": "true",
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "TEST",
            "id": "cEpPxopz",
            "info": {
                "description": "TEST",
                "eventLocation": "TEST",
                "dailyActivity": "true",
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Example",
            "id": "jnTMr_r7",
            "info": {
                "description": "example",
                "eventLocation": "Exmaple",
                "dailyActivity": "true",
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        }
    ],
    "",
    "",
    ""
],
]
```

Comment: How does this data structure look to you for your use case?
`var desiredResult = { "01-05-2020" : [ ObjectForThisDate1 ], "01-06-2020" : [ ObjectForThisDate1, ObjectForThisDate2 ]......}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, except for few minor tweaks

- You should only use map function when you want to return the array of the same size as original. Here is not the case. The length for data is 5 but your final answer will have 3 items in the array. So, `forEach is better suited`. Pick the values and push into new array.
  *For loop can also be used*.
- The outer and inner map were returning `""` which was getting included in the final result (due to map function). Use forEach and push the results into array.
  Read more here: [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)
- While using forEach, only the values containing the data need to be pushed in the final result. So, we need to put length check for > 0.

Have modified the code in the snippet below:

```js
var dates = [
  "01-06-2020",
  "01-07-2020",
  "01-08-2020",
  "01-10-2020",
  "02-04-2020"
]

var arrayOfObjects = [{"title":"Group President","id":"TpNY1SU_","info":{"description":"hi","eventLocation":"change","dailyActivity":"false","startDate":"01-06-2020"}},{"title":"TEST","id":"cEpPxopz","info":{"description":"TEST","eventLocation":"TEST","dailyActivity":"true","startDate":"01-07-2020"}},{"title":"Example","id":"jnTMr_r7","info":{"description":"example","eventLocation":"Exmaple","dailyActivity":"true","startDate":"01-07-2020"}}]

var endResult = []
dates.forEach(function(item) {
  var arrayOfEvents = [];
  var events = arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(value) {
    if (item === value.info.startDate) {
      arrayOfEvents.push(value)
    }
  });
  
  if(arrayOfEvents.length > 0) endResult.push(arrayOfEvents)

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(endResult, null, 4))
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Thank you Sunil! This is exactly what I was going for. I have checked your reponse for the correct answer.