# How to push an array with objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am a newbie here so my question may sound stupid.

I have an array with multiple objects and I am not sure how to push the key name of each object to an array.

This is my code:

```
var ingredients = [
    { id: 1, name: "onion", mineralsUnit: "mg", water: 89.11 },
    { id: 2, name: "carrot", calcium: 23, iron: 0.21, otherUnit: "g", water: 89.11 },
    { id: 3, name: "peanut", iron: 0.21, otherUnit: "g", water: 89.11 }
];
```

and I've created a new empty array where I want to add just the name from the first array

```
var myIngredients = [];
```

I've tried that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
    myIngredients.push(ingredients[i]);
}
```

but it returns the entire array and even though I select in here ingredients[I] what element I want to pick it's still not working. 
If someone has an idea I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're just pushing all of the `ingredients` elements into `myIngredients` by cycling on `ingredients`. `i` will be the index of the `ingredients` array, so you're actually not choosing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't forget the comma after peanut!

```
var myIngredients = [];

ingredients.forEach(
  ingredient =>
  myIngredients.push(ingredient.name)
)

console.log(myIngredients)
```

Comment: if you use arrow function, map is better than foreach

Comment: btw map under the hood does a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

with es6 you can use [map](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

try `myIngredients = ingredients.map(ingredient => ingredients.name)`

Comment: Even the foreach way has been chosen, I still recommend to use map which is more clean. this answer may help (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49549799/12704953 ) @Alexandra

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. This will push the `name` value of every object in the `ingredients` array

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
  myIngredients.push(ingredients[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function:

```js
var ingredients = [
  { id: 1, name: "onion", mineralsUnit: "mg", water: 89.11},
  { id: 2, name: "carrot", calcium: 23, iron: 0.21, otherUnit: "g", water: 89.11 },
  { id: 3, name: "peanut", iron: 0.21, otherUnit: "g", water: 89.11, }
];

var myIngredients = ingredients.map(e => e.name);

console.log(myIngredients);
```