# Had this error in VS CODE TERMINAL: Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, cart

im trying to run this code for cart details and i got an error, yet i couldnt obtain the result due to the error above,the error points directly to  the  (cartDetail.map )The code looks correct but coulnt figure out where the error is. id like anyone to assist with a fix.

```
 useEffect(() => {

       let cartItems = [];
       if (props.user.userData && props.user.userData.cart) {
           if (props.user.userData.cart.length > 0) {
               props.user.userData.cart.forEach(item => {
                   cartItems.push(item.id)
               });
               dispatch(getCartItems(cartItems, props.user.userData.cart))
                   .then((response) => {
                       if (response.payload.length > 0) {
                           calculateTotal(response.payload)
                       }
                   })
           }
       }

   }, [props.user.userData])

   const calculateTotal = (cartDetail) => {
       let total = 0;

       cartDetail.map(item => {
           total += parseInt(item.price, 10) * item.quantity
       });

       setTotal(total)
       setShowTotal(true)
   }
```

Comment: Use `forEach` instead of `map`. `map` is for getting one array from another by applying a function (which necessarily must return a value) to each element - if you just want to "do something" with each element, as here, `forEach` is the correct tool.

Comment: Thanks. tried it and i didnt get any error

Comment: @cssyphus happy to do so, but the reason I didn't do that in the first place was that I feel sure this has been asked before - but I confess I was too lazy to look for a duplicate myself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)