# constant declarations with forEach loop

Tags: javascript, constants

What's wrong with the code? How to get a doubled value in doubleSalaries?

```
const salaries= [
  { amount: 10 },
  { amount: 45 },
  { amount: 90 }
];

const doubleSalaries = salaries.forEach(salaries => ({
...salary,
 amount: salary.amount * 2
}));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: There is no expicit return to `forEach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map the array

```js
const salaries= [
  { amount: 10 },
  { amount: 45 },
  { amount: 90 }
];

const doubleSalaries = salaries.map(salary => ({amount: salary.amount * 3}));

console.log(doubleSalaries);
```

Comment: Still a typo , no `salary` in callback

Comment: thnx a lot) fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map() method:

```js
const salaries= [
  { amount: 10 },
  { amount: 45 },
  { amount: 90 }
];

const doubleSalaries = salaries.map(x => x.amount * 3);

console.log(doubleSalaries)
```