# How to put elements of an array into html table rows and columns

Tags: html, css, node.js, arrays, html-table

I need to put each element of an array into the corresponding table column, but currently it just puts the entire array into the first column. I feel like this solution will be a simple nested for loop but I am unsure, would appreciate any help. Thanks!

index.html

```
<div id="PersonContainer" class="DBcontainer">
        <form action='/addPerson' method="GET"></form>
        <table class="center" id="personTable">
            <caption>People Table</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Hooks ID</th>
                    <th>Soft Plastic ID</th>
                    <th>Rods ID</th>
                    <th>Number of Hooks</th>
                    <th>Number of Soft Plastics</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button type="button" onclick="displayPerson()">Click Me</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

index.html script

```
<script>
        function displayPerson() {
            // console.log('test');
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var person = xhttp.responseText;
                    var element = document.getElementById("personTable");
                    var result = JSON.parse(person).map((item) => Object.values(item));
                    for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                        element.innerHTML += '<td>' + result[i] + '</td>';
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "/AddPerson", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

the xhttp.responseText

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Tyler","last_name":"Marlow","hooks_id":1,"sp_id":1,"rods_id":1,"num_hooks":10,"num_sp":30},{"id":2,"first_name":"Jon","last_name":"Marlow","hooks_id":2,"sp_id":1,"rods_id":1,"num_hooks":50,"num_sp":200}]
```

Also note that when another person is added I would like another row to be added to the table with the values in proper columns

Comment: 1. Fix the HTML so the table has a thead and tbody 2. post an example of the xhttp.responseText so we can help you loop. Assuming the AJAX works

Comment: element.innerHTML adds cells to the table, not to rows in the tbody - add the id to the tbody instead of the table

Comment: Also why map and then loop, when you can just loop: `JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText).forEach(item => 
element.innerHTML += \`<tr><td>${item.something}</td><td>${item.somethingelse}</td></tr>\`);`

Comment: can you attach xhttp.responseText as an  example?

Comment: xhttp response added

Answer (score 0):

```js
function displayPerson() {
  // console.log('test');            
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var person = xhttp.responseText;
      var element = document.getElementById("personTable");
      var rows = ``;
      JSON.parse(person).forEach(item => {
        var row = `<tr>`;
        row += `<td>${item.first_name}</td>`;
        row += `<td>${item.last_name}</td>`;
        row += `<td>${item.hooks_id}</td>`;
        row += `<td>${item.sp_id}</td>`;
        row += `<td>${item.rods_id}</td>`;
        row += `<td>${item.num_hooks}</td>`;
        row += `<td>${item.num_sp}</td>`;
        row += `</tr>`;
        rows += row;
      });
      element.innerHTML = rows;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/AddPerson", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="PersonContainer" class="DBcontainer">
  <form action='/addPerson' method="GET">
    <table class="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Hooks ID</th>
          <th>Soft Plastic ID</th>
          <th>Rods ID</th>
          <th>Number of Hooks</th>
          <th>Number of Soft Plastics</th>
        </tr>
        <thead>
          <tbody id="personTable">
          </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="button" onclick="displayPerson()">Click Me</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: person.foreach is not a function is the error I get

Comment: person is not an array?

Comment: And item.value are all undefined

Comment: i thought person (xhttp.responseText) was array according to your example.

Comment: I had to json parse to make it an array

Comment: then try with `JSON.parse(person).forEach...`

Comment: Do you know why item.value would be undefined?

Comment: i can't find `value` key in your json response.

Comment: item is the each json object of the array, so you can access item.first_name, item.last_name ,...

Comment: item.first_name comes back as undefined

Comment: As well as the resut of them, i used item.value as an example to refer to all of them

Comment: only use `JSON.parse(person).forEach`, not `.map`

Comment: so .map makes it undefined when trying to access it by item.?

Comment: map and forEach are almost same regarding the loop array, but have a difference. refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: anyway, i think just replace `forEach` with `map` will work as well, since there is no return value for the map in my answer.

Comment: however, best practice is to use forEach in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a new row onto a table in JavaScript can be done with the insertRow function and adding a cell to a row can be done with the insertCell function.

So in your code (depending on exactly what your parsed JSON looks like) in your for loop you are going to do something like:

row = element.insertRow(i); // add a new row to your table
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = 
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 
and so on
....
But of course you'd put the insertCell line into a for loop as well.