# Calcul with useState in a map function javascript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello guys I have an array like this :

```
[
 {
   "name": "test",
   "amount": 794.651786,
   "id": "60477897fd230655b337a1e6"
 },
 {
   "name": "test2",
   "amount": 10.80918,
   "id": "60477bfbfd230655b337a1e9"
 }
]
```

And i wan't to make the total of every amount.

I tried by using the useState hook like this :

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(Number);
array.map((item) => {

 setTotal(total + item.amount);

});
```

but it doesn't seems to work as expected.

Comment: How do you expect it to work and how does it currently work?

Comment: First and foremost, I invite you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: What is `array` - in `array.map` - is it a prop? Is it some other state? The reason is, it's likely you don't want to use `state` here at all. To clarify further, if `array` is some other state or some other prop, then `total` isn't state, it's `computed state` and you just want `useMemo` (or nothing at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, see docs.

```
setTotal(array.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.amount, 0))
```

I invite you to read this [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map) as well. You should never use `.map` like this. For this use case, use `.forEach` instead.

Comment: This is far better than calling `setState` in a loop, but I still don't think the OP should be using state here at all.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to update the state with the minimum calls needed.
so first, I would do it like this:

```
let _total = 0;
array.forEach((item) => {
   _total += item.amount;
});
setTotal(_total);
```

That said, You would want to **only** execute this if `array` has changed. Assuming array is a prop, this can be done easily with `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let _total = 0;
    array.forEach((item) => {
        _total += item.amount;
    });
setTotal(_total);
},[array]);
```

Hope this helps you get a full picture of what the best practice would be. Also you can check out the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) to get a better understanding on where is best to call `setState`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: @jperl thanks. Forgot to use forEach. Already edited!

Comment: Yes that's perfect ! I learn more everyday about optimisation, thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

My comment wasn't addressed but I'm going to add an answer which addresses my concern - `total` shouldn't be state at all.

`total` most likely isn't state - it's computed state - i.e. it's derived from other state and/or props.

If that's the case (99% that it is) it's not correct to set total as state, that just makes for more code and more complicated debugging:

Examples:

When the source of data is a prop:

```
const Cart = ({someItemsInMyCart}) => {
   const total = useMemo(() => someItemsInMyCart.reduce((acc,item) => acc+item.amount,0),[someItemsInMyCart]);

   return (/* some JSX */);
}
```

When the source of data is state:

```
const Cart = () => {
   const [items,setItems] = useState([]);
   const total = useMemo(() => items.reduce((acc,item) => acc+item.amount,0),[items]);

   return (/* some JSX */);
}
```

You can write those two examples above and completely leave out the `useMemo`, which is just a perf optimization, because reducing an array in that manner is pretty darn fast unless you're dealing with 1000s of items.

Comment: thx ! I was thinking a state would be nice but you prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

array.map((item) => {
 setTotal(prevCount => prevCount + item.amount);    
});
```