# React/Javascript - Render a List of Values Based On Same Object Keys Within an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```js
const arr = [
{name: "Bill", email: "bill@email.com"},
{name: "Suzy", email: "suzy@email.com"},
{name: "Jill", email: "Jill@email.com"},
]
```

I would like to return each value in an `<li>`. One list for names, one list for emails. Like this:

```js
return (
  <>
    <div className="names">
      <ul>
        {arr.forEach((item) => {
          return <li>item.name</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div className="emails">
      <ul>
        {arr.forEach((item) => {
          return <li>item.email</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

so that it looks like this:

```
- Bill
- Suzy 
- Jill

- bill@email.com
- suzy@email.com
- jill@email.com
```

But, of course what I am doing does not look like this, which is why I am asking this question. What can I do with my array of objects to generate the desired list layout? Thanks.

Comment: une `map` instead of `forEach` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in JSX, with your code:

```
{
  arr.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{item.email}</li> 
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

import React, { useState } from 'react';

```
const Component=()=> {

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    arr = [
      {name: "Bill", email: "bill@email.com"},
      {name: "Suzy", email: "suzy@email.com"},
      {name: "Jill", email: "Jill@email.com"},
    ]
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="names">
        <ul>
          //this map will render all the names inside arr array one by one inside an li
          {data.arr.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{item.name}</li> 
          ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div className="emails">
        //this map will render all the emails inside arr array one by one inside an li
        {data.arr.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item.email}</li> 
        ))  
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```