# Change key values in array of objects to have same value of sibling key

Tags: javascript, angular

So i have a similar array of objects like this one:

```
this.array = [{apple: 2, oranges: 100}, {apple: 4, oranges: 120}, {apple: 6, oranges: 110}];
```

I want to iterate through the array and update the values of oranges to have the same values as apple. So i would have the following result:

```
this.array = [{apple: 2, oranges: 2}, {apple: 4, oranges: 4}, {apple: 6, oranges: 6}];
```

what is a good way to get that result?

I tried to do the following but did not work

```
this.array = this.array.forEach(fruit => fruit.oranges === fruit.apple);
```

Comment: `fruit.oranges === fruit.apple` tests for strict equality - you want `fruit.oranges = fruit.apple` - and you also DONT want `this.array = ` ... since `array.forEach` returns undefined

Comment: @adiga - yep, there's a difference between using .map and .forEach ... it may be an important one ... code in question mutates the contents of this.array ... .map replaces this.array with a new array ... completely different semantics

Comment: @JaromandaX I know about that. But, that doesn't answer OP's simple question. Not everyone wants to create a new array all the time.

Comment: @adiga - I was agreeing with you :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's understand your code:

> ```
> array.forEach(fruit => fruit.oranges === fruit.apple);
> ```

Let's expand the callback function:

```
array.forEach(fruit => {
  return fruit.oranges === fruit.apple;
});
```

The `forEach` method should be used only when you want to *iterate* over each element of the array. It won't do anything with the value you return from the given callback.

You could, however, modify the `===` operator (which shall be used to **compare** two values) to use the `=` operator to **reassign** the value of the **original** `fruit`'s `orange` property.

Like so:

```js
const arr = [
  { apple: 2, oranges: 100 },
  { apple: 4, oranges: 120 },
  { apple: 6, oranges: 110 }
];

arr.forEach((fruit) => {
  // Reassign the `oranges` property with the `apple` value:
  fruit.oranges = fruit.apple
});

console.log(arr);
```

Notice that `forEach` does not return the array. In this case, we are just iterating over each element and modifying each element's `oranges` property.

Another option, when you **do NOT want to modify** the original values is to use `Array.prototype.map` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34426458/7445826) to find out the differences between `map` and `forEach`.

Something like:

```js
const arr = [
  { apple: 2, oranges: 100 },
  { apple: 4, oranges: 120 },
  { apple: 6, oranges: 110 }
];

const newArr = arr.map((obj) => ({
  // Forward the apple property:
  apple: obj.apple,
  // Assign a new value to the oranges property:
  oranges: obj.apple
}));

console.log(newArr);
```

I must add that with that code, you will not, in fact, modify the array nor its original objects. You are instead creating a new array (returned by `map`) with new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Better map the array instead of using foreach

```js
this.array = [{apple: 2, oranges: 100}, {apple: 4, oranges: 120}, {apple: 6, oranges: 110}];
this.array = this.array.map(fruit => ({...fruit, oranges : fruit.apple }));
console.log(this.array)
```

Comment: Please point out their issue before suggesting `map`