# Loop over complex array structures with best practice and lowest complexity

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, big-o, javascript-objects

I am calling an API that returns

```
 [{
        Id:string,
        Value:string,
        Value2: 
          [{Id:string,Value3:string}] ,
 {
        Id:string,
        Value:string,
        Value2: 
          [{Id:string,Value3:string}] 
 }]
```

How do i loop over value 2 with lowest complexity and best approach in JS

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your issue but you can simply map over your table items like that (assuming a variable called `table` holds your data):

```
table.map((item) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item.Value2))
})
```

And if you want to loop over the values of Value2:

```
table.map((item) => {
  item.Value2.map((subitem) => {
    console.log(subitem.Value3)
  })
})
```

Comment: Side note: use `forEach` for those examples (https://stackoverflow.com/q/34426458/1225328).

Comment: @sp00m yes you're right if the original poster does need to log the value. But since I am not sure about the expected operation, I let .map() to be sure

Comment: Two loops inside each other isn't the best practice

Comment: So you have to denormalize your data structure before