# Array of string to array of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wondering how to convert an array of strings

```
lines = ['101','010','110'];
```

to an array of arrays like this:

```
x = [
[1,0,1],
[0,1,0],
[1,1,0]'
]
```

I already tried

```
x = (lines.forEach(e => (e.split(''))))
```

and realized `String.split` doesnt mutate the current string. So my next step was to create a new array with these values.

```
x = new Array(lines.forEach(e => (e.split(''))))
```

My thoughts behind this line:
The code should take an element (e) of the lines array and apply the split funtion to it. (which is does when i `console.log()` it.) BUT it doesnt apply it to the new array.

Maybe the problem is, that it doesn't loop through `x` but maybe i overlook another fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.map(Number)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) result to convert them to a Number as expected

```js
const lines = ['101','010','110'];
const res = lines.map(l => l.split('').map(Number));

console.log(res);
```

```json
[
  [
    1,
    0,
    1
  ],
  [
    0,
    1,
    0
  ],
  [
    1,
    1,
    0
  ]
]
```

---

Regarding your [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) solution, since `forEach` does not return anything, `x` stays `undefined`

You could define an empty array, and push your `split()` into that empty array, but using `map()` is a more readable/clean solution.

For more information about `map()` vs `forEach()`, please take a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426481/5625547).

Comment: @OP - For what it's worth, in *general*, using a function as a `map` callback that isn't designed for it is chancy, but it's fine in the case of the `Number` function (it wouldn't be for `parseInt`, though, as an example). For more number conversion options (since `Number` will give you `0` for `""`), see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).

Comment: Would be good to explain why `forEach` didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for this futher explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As per @OstoneO's answer, [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the most appropriate method to use, hence it would be my first choice.

[`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)'s return value is undefined because it's not designed to return a value; it is a loop and should be used as such:

```js
const lines = ['101','010','110'];

const x = [];
lines.forEach( line => x.push( line.split('').map(n => +n) ) );

console.log( x );
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method,

```
 ['101','010','110'].reduce((acc,val,index)=>{
    acc[index] = [...val.split("").map((item)=>parseInt(item))];
    return acc;

}
,[]);
```