# Nothing is showing when I loop through the array using forEach in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to show the blog author and blog title in the array on my html page but nothing is displayed. I used the map method and it worked but the forEach method shows nothing. I will like a solution in for loop and forEach loop
Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {

const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([
    { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Welcome party!', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'yoshi', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Web dev top tips', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 3 }
]);


return ( 
    <div className="home">
      

         {blogs.forEach((blog) => {
            <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                <h2>{ blog.title }</h2>
                <p>Written by{ blog.author }</p>
            </div>
        })} 
       
    </div>
      
 );
 }export default Home;
```

Comment: forEach returns undefined, therefore nothing will be displayed. 
Is there something unsatisfactory about using map?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: @ A.R.SEIF thanks for the link, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try it with map. 
 `{blogs.map((blog) =>  {<div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}><h2>{ blog.title }</h2><p>Written by{ blog.author }</p></div>})}`

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use .map for this like

```
blogs.map((blog) => (
      <div> //your code </div>
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map instead because the map method returns a new array by applying the callback function on each element of an array, while the **forEach method doesn't return anything**.

so you have to use it like this.

```js
{blogs.map((blog) => {
            <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                <h2>{ blog.title }</h2>
                <p>Written by{ blog.author }</p>
            </div>
        })}
```

like this.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I really appreciate. I already used map but I was questing for knowledge.
can I used for loop?

Comment: no, you can't.
a foreach loop processes an instance of each element in a collection(like array) in turn, while a for loop can work with any data and is not restricted to collection elements alone

Comment: ok thanks
 I really appreciate

Comment: I don't have enough reputation just yet