# Array of object value printing in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I want to print expected output values in two loop using map, Can you please help me.

```
var data=[{'2021':['Q2 2021','Q3 2021','Q4 2021']},
     {'2022':['Q1 2022','Q2 2022']}
    ]
   
   data.map((obj,ind)=>{
    console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    Object.keys(obj).map((yearQuarter, i) => {
                  console.log(obj[yearQuarter]);
                  })
   })
   //getting output
   //['2022']
   //['Q1 2022', 'Q2 2022']
   //Expected Output
   //'2022'
   //'Q1 2022`
   //'Q2 2022`
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use replace to make `obj[yearQuarter]` print by multiple lines

```js
var data=[{'2021':['Q2 2021','Q3 2021','Q4 2021']},
     {'2022':['Q1 2022','Q2 2022']}
    ]

data.map((obj,ind)=>{
  console.log(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((yearQuarter, i) => {
      console.log(obj[yearQuarter].toString().replace('[]','').replaceAll(',','\n'))
   })
})
```

Comment: don't use `map()` as `forEach()`. [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Comment: This is not working in react

Comment: @SupriyaKumari What's the prolem,it has nothing to do with react,you might need to change `\n` to `<br/>`

Comment: Still not working, is there any other way?

Comment: @SupriyaKumari need to know more details about your code,maybe we need a chat

Comment: I want to create menu and submenu using two map loop in react js, and with ablove given code, subarray values coming in single line

Comment: @SupriyaKumari,you need to add you code,also as I said,you need to use `<br/>` instead of `\n`

Comment: <br/> not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248962/discussion-between-lucumt-and-supriya-kumari).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to print both key as well as the values (In a string format). If Yes, You are iterating the input object in a right way. Just to print the values, you can use [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Live Demo **:**

```js
var data = [
  {'2021':['Q2 2021','Q3 2021','Q4 2021']},
  {'2022':['Q1 2022','Q2 2022']}
];

data.map((obj,ind)=>{
  Object.keys(obj).map((yearQuarter, i) => {
    console.log(`${yearQuarter} : ${obj[yearQuarter].join(', ')}`);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a complete line with newline characters and print it all at once

```js
const data = [{'2021':['Q2 2021','Q3 2021','Q4 2021']},{'2022':['Q1 2022','Q2 2022']}];

const renderYear = (obj) => Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([year, quarters]) => `${year}\n${quarters.join("\n")}`);
  
const renderYears = (arr) => arr.flatMap(renderYear).join("\n")

console.log(renderYears(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```